# Blender python : Where is the output when running script from blender text editor

Tags: python

Where is the output is displayed or piped? like when simply doing : 
print('test')

i can't see any result in any window? not in console etc. So where is the output has been sent to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *will* show up in the console. If you're using Windows, go to Help > Toggle system console. [Here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Fade/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Console_window) is a guide for other OS's.

Comment: I see. i thought it goes to python console. Thanks a lot.